# How to set multiple values at one time to Ext.data.Model?

Tags: extjs, model

In `Ext.data.Model` class we have `set(fieldName, newValue)` method which sets one model field to the given value.

How to set multiple values at one time? Something like:

```
Ext.data.Model.set({
    field1: 'value1',
    field2: 345,
    field3: true
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not possible, but as per my understanding you only want to merge this different calls for setting a value in model when you need to notify about changes in model only once to store so store will only fire `update` event once

If this is the case for you then you can use `beginEdit` and `endEdit` functions

```
var model = new Ext.data.Model();

model.beginEdit();

model.set('field1', 'value1');
model.set('field2', 345);
model.set('field3', true);

model.endEdit();
```

Comment: This is not true at all, the set() method can also handle an object setting multiple parameters as Liverbool says. It's not documented  but has always been possible. See the source code. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/source/Model.html#Ext-data-Model-method-set

Answer (score 10):

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model

You can set the field to set, or an object containing key/value pairs

```js
record.set({
    field1: value,
    field2: value2
});

// or 

record.set(field1, value);
record.set(field2, value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new record which returns a blank record with all the model fields

```
//this one is for the grid model

var blank_record  = Ext.create(grid.store.model);
```

Create an object to set the new values to fields

```
 var new_record = {
        'field1':'value1',
        'field2':'value2',
        'field3':'value3'
    };
```

then set the object values to the blank record

```
 blank_record.set(new_record);
```

Further if u want to add the newly created record to the grid

```
grid.store.add(blank_record);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but here's another way to do it:

```
var rec = new Ext.data.Model({
    field1: 'value1',
    field2: 'value2',
    field3: 'value3'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you do this with just `Ext.create()` ?
As explained here:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.ModelManager-method-create

Comment: I'm modifying existing record. To add new model to store we can just `Ext.Store.add({field1: 'value1',  field2: 345, field3: true})`